# The argument type 'JsObject' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'BuildContext'.dart

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

[image: Navigator.of(context).pop;]

I am getting an error it is saying "The argument type 'JsObject' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'BuildContext'.dart"

> > error on this part  Navigator.of(context).pop()

Comment: We need to see where the `context` used in line 22 is defined to try to help you. Judging by what I can see, you're simply trying to use the argument `context` of the `build` function in another function, or you have overriden it with a variable with the same name.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've imported by mistake the `dart:js` module. If so, just remove it:

```dart
import 'dart:js'; // <- Remove this import
```

[The `dart:js` module exports a global `context` of type `JsObject`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.17.6/dart-js/context.html) and its type conflicts with the `BuildContext` type.